# Is $\hat \beta$ of general least squares an orthogonal projection?

Tags: least-squares, estimators, generalized-least-squares, projection

$\hat \beta_{GLS} = (X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}Y \\
Y=X\hat \beta_{GLS} + \epsilon=X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}Y + \epsilon = \\X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}Y + (I-X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1})Y$

It is clear that the projection part ($H =  X(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}$) is idempotent, but it appears that it is not symmetric.

Does this implies that the projection here is not orthogonal (since any [orthogonal projection is symmetric](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/456354/342736))? Does this also mean that it is not a unique projection?

Comment: how did the leftmost $X$ in the formula appear?

Comment: For GLS, a matrix $H$ is *symmetric* if and only if $VH^\prime = HV.$  When you adopt a geometric interpretation of $H,$ $X,$ and $V,$ this fact is immediate; but it is also straightforward to verify this with matrix algebra.

Comment: @gunes yeah fixed the notation a bit

Comment: @whuber I don't understand. $VH'$ *is* equal $HV$... but I don't see how this proves that $H$ is symmetric. $HV$ is symmetric though.

Comment: "Symmetric" always means *with respect to the underlying quadratic form."  For OLS that form is a multiple of the identity; for GLS, it is a multiple of $V.$